# The bracha on Pita Chips

Tags: blessing, food, mezonot-beracha, hamotzi-beracha

What *Bracha* should one make on pita chips, *Hamotzi or Mezonos ?*

Answer (score 2):

I heard from my Rebbi *Rav Menachem Feifer Shlita״h* that it depends. If it was made from existing pita it is Hamotzi, but if it is made ' from scratch ' it is Mezonos.
[Check out this source from a Brachos Site](http://www.berachot.org/Q+A/index.html#45)

Answer (score 1):

I was sure it was hamotzi but your question made me doubt and check. It is indeed a *machloket* and seems to depend on the specific product.

For Stacy's Pita chips, the OU poskim say it is *hamotzi* but they acknowledge others say *mezonot* (see [here](http://matzav.com/readers-matzav-pita-chips-bracha-issue/)).

[dinonline says](http://dinonline.org/2011/11/27/berachah-for-pitta-chips/), like your source and Rav, that it depends if the chips were initially baked as a pita then fried (in which case it is *hamotzi*) or directly baked as a snack (then *mezonot*). Most relevant quote from R Yehoshua Pfeffer is

> If the pita bread is baked [initially] as regular bread, and can be
>   eaten as bread (even if not well done), it follows that the berachah
>   will remain *hamotzi* even after it is made into chips. This is because
>   once made into regular bread, the bread will not lose its status by
>   being cut up and re-baked (see Mishnah Berurah 168:62;
>   Minchas Yitzchak 1:71:8; Yaskil Avdi 1:9).
>
> If the initial baking is for the purpose of “chips” then the berachah
>   will be *mezonot* (see Kehilas Yaakov Berachos 16).

PS. Interestingly, in Israel, some *hekhserim* will print the bracha abbreviation on the package in difficult cases like these

Comment: FWIW, you see the bracha mentioned on many U.S made products, also. It's esp. common to see on Pesach "cake" the words "birchato shehakol".

Comment: @DanF interesting. I didn't see it but lived in the US a while back now. Reason I mentioned it is the first link I cited mentions OU doesn't do it

Comment: @mbloch The hekhsherim are not taking responsibility for the brachot printed TTBOMK. It's just someones friendly opinion

Comment: @danf that is just a warning that its not gebrokhts so no flour. Such warnings exist in nearly no other context

Comment: @DoubleAA It is mainly to inform people that it's not gebrokhts, but, it also serves to inform of the bracha. Another "context" I have seen is on some "fruity" wines such as sangria and raspberry wine which had the wording "birchato shehakol" as well. Similar idea - it was mainly fruit juice vs. grape juice.

Comment: @DanF Almost exclusively brachos printed on food items in the US are found on hassidic hechsherim. While relying on the hechsherim in general is suspect, most people are lenient as they are usually really just OU products relabled. Relying on the brachos is not advised for non hassidic Jews as their opinions differ from other orthodox groups in many many instances. Their leniency to make mezonos in situations everyone else makes hamotzie, their shehakol on certain products other groups make a haadama on etc. It's really just better to ignore the 'bracha' and ask your own halachik authority.

Answer (score 0):

The star k holds that on commercial pita chips you always make a mezonos.

"You are correct that if pita chips are made from leftover bread then they would be hamotzi. However, commercially made pita chips are not made from leftover bread but rather are produced with intent at the outset to make pita chips. Therefore, they do not have the halachic status of bread and are pas habah bekisnin, requiring a mezonos if eaten as a snack. כן פסק הגרש"ז אויערבאך זצ"ל הובא בספר וזאת הברכה עמ' 21"

Here is the link: [star k website](https://www.star-k.org/prev_questions) It is a list of questions so search for the pita chips question.